# SQL Query that reports number of universities by town in descending order

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a SQL query that reports the universities in Cambridge, New York City, and Chicago. It is only supposed to output the Town and number of universities in each town in descending order. Not sure what the condition would look like nor what I am selecting besides town.

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT Town
FROM Universities
WHERE Town = "New York City" OR Town = "Cambridge" OR Town = "Chicago"
ORDER BY Town DESC
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description I would suggest you need a simple aggregate query like the following - note you can use *in* here and also string literals are delimited by single quotes.

```
select Town, Count(*) as NumberOfUniversities
from Universities
where Town in ('New York City', 'Cambridge', 'Chicago')
group by Town
order by NumberOfUniversities desc;
```